# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1/x+\log(\tan(x)))$

Tags: limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1/x+\log(\tan(x))).$$

I can't transform $\log(\tan(x))$ to some $0/0$ form so that I can use L'Hospital rule.

Comment: What is the limit of $\frac{\log(\tan(x))}{1/x}$ as $x\to 0^+$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\log(\tan x ) \right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1+x\log(\tan x )}{x} =\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1+x\log x}{x}= \\ =\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1-\frac{\log \frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

The expression under limit can be written as $$\frac{1}{x}+\log x+\log\frac{\tan x} {x} $$ and the last term tends to $0$ so that the desired limit is equal to the limit of the expression $$\frac{1+x\log x} {x} $$ The numerator tends to $1$ and denominator tends to $0$ through positive values and therefore the desired limit is $\infty$.